# Matching Something Against Array List Using Where Object

Tags: regex, powershell

I've found multiple examples of what I'm trying here, but for some reason it's not working.

I have a list of regular expressions that I'm checking against a single value and I can't seem to get a match.

I'm attempting to match domains. e.g. gmail.com, yahoo.com, live.com, etc.

I am importing a csv to get the domains and have debugged this code to make sure the values are what I expect. e.g. "gmail.com"

**Regular expression examples AKA $FinalWhiteListArray**

```
(?i)gmail\.com
(?i)yahoo\.com
(?i)live\.com
```

**Code**

```
Function CheckDirectoryForCSVFilesToSearch {

    $global:CSVFiles = Get-ChildItem $Global:Directory -recurse -Include *.csv | % {$_.FullName} #removed -recurse
}

Function ImportCSVReports {
    Foreach ($CurrentChangeReport in $global:CSVFiles) {
        $global:ImportedChangeReport = Import-csv $CurrentChangeReport
    }
}
Function CreateWhiteListArrayNOREGEX {
    $Global:FinalWhiteListArray = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    $WhiteListPath = $Global:ScriptRootDir + "\" + "WhiteList.txt"
    $Global:FinalWhiteListArray= Get-Content $WhiteListPath
}
$Global:ScriptRootDir = Split-Path -Path $psISE.CurrentFile.FullPath
$Global:Directory = $Global:ScriptRootDir + "\" + "Reports to Search" + "\" #Where to search for CSV files

CheckDirectoryForCSVFilesToSearch
ImportCSVReports
CreateWhiteListArrayNOREGEX

Foreach ($Global:Change in $global:ImportedChangeReport){
    If (-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Global:Change.Previous_Provider_Contact_Email))){
       $pos = $Global:Change.Provider_Contact_Email.IndexOf("@")
       $leftPart = $Global:Change.Provider_Contact_Email.Substring(0, $pos)
       $Global:Domain = $Global:Change.Provider_Contact_Email.Substring($pos+1)

       $results = $Global:FinalWhiteListArray | Where-Object { $_ -match $global:Domain}
}

}
```

Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Comment: what is in each of `$ListOfDomains` &  `$FinalWhiteListArray`?

Comment: Edited the post to be more descriptive.

Comment: As the `-match` operator is RegEx based: `$ListOfDomains = @("gmail\.com","yahoo\.com","live\.com")` or using alternation `$ListOfDomains = "gmail\.com|yahoo\.com|live\.com" BTW the operators in PowerShell are by default case insensitive, so the `(?i)` isn't necessary.
`

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I've updated the code to include everything.

Comment: @MrMr - thanks! now i can tell that you have your regex on the wrong side of the `-match` operator. [*grin*] try swapping those two and you otta get your matches. ///// i agree with LotPings that you have no need for the `(?i)` stuff, AND that you likely otta use a regex OR of those regex patterns.

Comment: Hah, thank you! That did the trick.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey If you post the answer I'd be glad to give you credit.

Comment: @MrMr - kool! thanks for the reminder ... and i'm glad you got it working as needed! [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem with your current code is that you put the regex on the *left* side of the `-match` operator. [*grin*] swap that and your code otta work.

taking into account what LotPings pointed out about case sensitivity and using a regex OR symbol to make one test per URL, here's a demo of some of that. the `\b` is for word boundaries, the `|` is the regex OR symbol. the `$RegexURL_WhiteList` section builds that regex pattern from the 1st array. if i haven't made something clear, please ask ...

```
$URL_WhiteList = @(
    'gmail.com'
    'yahoo.com'
    'live.com'
    )
$RegexURL_WhiteList = -join @('\b' ,(@($URL_WhiteList |
    ForEach-Object {
        [regex]::Escape($_)
        }) -join '|\b'))

$NeedFiltering = @(
    'example.com/this/that'
    'GMail.com'
    'gmailstuff.org/NothingElse'
    'NotReallyYahoo.com'
    'www.yahoo.com'
    'SomewhereFarAway.net/maybe/not/yet'
    'live.net'
    'Live.com/other/another'
    )

foreach ($NF_Item in $NeedFiltering)
    {
    if ($NF_Item -match $RegexURL_WhiteList)
        {
        '[ {0} ] matched one of the test URLs.' -f $NF_Item 
        }
    }
```

output ...

```
[ GMail.com ] matched one of the test URLs.
[ www.yahoo.com ] matched one of the test URLs.
[ Live.com/other/another ] matched one of the test URLs.
```